# Side panel to top. Is there any other solution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make button to top on the side panel. But I' facing a problem because I need my SIDE panel to act on scroll but not the whole body. There's the code for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="side">
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>

</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const side = document.getElementById('side');
const top = side.offsetTop;

if (top > 10){
    document.getElementById('topBtn').style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById('topBtn').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I didn't mentioned that this way is not working for me.

Comment: is the button position fixed? and the method is onscroll event listener?

Comment: `offsetTop` is how far the top of an element is offset against the top of its offset parent. This has little to do with scrolling, for that you want to look at the`scrollHeight` property.

Comment: Yes the button is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function topFunction() {
   document.body.scrollTop = 0;
   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
 }
```

```css
#topBtn{
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="side">
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>

</div>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that solution from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp
But i need to apear button on scroll of the SIDE panel. Not the whole BODY.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<body>
    <div id="side" style="overflow-y:scroll">
        <div id="top">...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>

        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>

        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>

        <div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>

        <button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
    </div>
</body>

// your jquery cdn script 
<script>

$(function() {
  $('#topBtn').animate({
    // Scroll to top of body
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500);
})();

</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it with plain javascript not jquery?